# How can I renderize a PDF into BMP fitting content to PDF page boundaries?

Tags: pdf, bitmap, type-conversion, ghostscript

I am getting a BMP from a PDF with GhostScript, but its content is not fitted into page boundaries. Even I try any option, I am not able to get the content fitted.

I've tried to generate the BMP with different GhostScript options, but noone seems to fit 100% ok the content.

This is the last command I tried. Please, don't expect it to have what I need, just copied & paste from tty.

```sh
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPSFitPage -sDEVICE=bmpmono -sOutputFile=Betlem.bmp -g1184x968 -c "<</PageSize [900 500]>> setpagedevice 0 0 translate" -c "<</PageOffset [-23 -100]>> setpagedevice" -f Betlem.pdf
```

I am expecting to get the content fitted into the BMP image borders, without exception of a pixel. I am using an OpenCV & Python function to extract content and fit in new image and this is the debug:

```
initial BMP image resolution = (872, 900)
BMP image resolution after fit content into new page = (541, 870)
```

Have a look to the following thread for the fitting funtion in Python:

[I can't find a way to fit contour on new image zero point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127734/i-cant-find-a-way-to-fit-contour-on-new-image-zero-point)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PSFitPage` for a PDF file, you should be using `PDFFitPage` or just `FitPage`.

Note that the 'fitting' in this case is fitting the PDF media size to the existing media. If the PDF content leaves white space around the edge of the media, then the resulting scaling will include that.

In addition you are using PostScript to offset the page origin, which **will** introduce white space, and you are trying to change the media size, which won't work because you've set `-dFIXEDMEDIA`. Using these in combination with any of the FitPage switches is not likely to work well.

Randomly stabbing at controls and copying bits of code intended to solve different problems isn't likely to help you I'm afraid.

Without seeing an example file I can't, of course, tell you how to solve your problem, and I'm not really sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. A bitmap with no white space ? A bitmap of a given size with no white space ? Something else ?

[Edit]

OK so looking at the PDF file, the media box is 11.69x8.27 inches, there is white space at the top, bottom, left and right between the marks on the page and the edge of the media.

Running this through Ghostscript, to TIFF at 72 dpi results in a file which Adobe Photoshop says is 11.694x8.264 inches and has white space at top bottom left and right, just like the PDF file.

By default Ghostscript uses the Media size from the PDF to render to, however you can change this. If you were to change the media size to (say) 5.8x4.14 inches, set -dFIXEDMEDIA and then rendered the PDF file what would happen is that the top and right hand side of the PDF file would be 'off the page' so you would only get the left hand portion rendered. Try this:

```
gs -DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=421 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=298 -dFIXEDMEDIA "A betlem m en vull anar(1).pdf"
```

You will see the white space is still present at bottom and left, and the top and right have fallen off the page.

Now, if you add `FitPage` that will scale the **original** media down until it fits the new media size (and all the content too, of course). If you try:

```
gs -DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=421 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=298 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dFitPage "A betlem m en vull anar(1).pdf"
```

You'll see that the output is the same physical dfimensions as the previous command, but now the whole of the PDF content can be seen because its been scaled down. You should also see that the distribution of white space has changed, because I didn't strictly divide by 2 in each direction. The `FitPage` switch scaled the content in both directions by the same amount, and distributed the extra space in the x direction evenly to each side, as new white space.

Now I've no clue what you mean by 'simmetric'. You can undoubtedly do what you want using Ghostscript and the PostScript language, but I don't know what it is you want. Pointing me at Python code isn't going to help I'm afraid, I don't speak Python.

I can say that Ghostscript does **not** add extra white space that isn't present in the original **unless** you mess with the rendering by addding parameters like FitPage and FIXEDMEDIA.

If you can explain what you are trying to achieve I can probably tell you what to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks at first by your answer! :- ) The PDF link is http://www.xn--estudiantladolaina-lvb.com/partitures/baixa/pdf/26 I am trying to generate a bmp in monochrome but simmetric from that PDF. And I want to try different resolutions until I see the best result... but, the GhostScript is adding spaces between page boundaries and also it is true that the PDF has white spaces. I just don't understand how GhostScript works even reading its doc.